# Generate Visual Studio Project Templates with CruiseControl.Net or MSBuild

Tags: visual-studio, templates, msbuild, cruisecontrol.net

I have a working workflow in CruiseControl.Net that successfully builds and tests an MSBuild project that is calling my Visual Studio 2010 solution.

How do I create Visual Studio project templates in either CruiseControl.Net or with MSBuild? The build server does not have Visual Studio 2010 installed.

Thanks for your time!

*Note:* This can be extended to any other solution that could be scripted with a batch as well, but I cannot install Visual Studio 2010 on the machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find out that creating a zip file with a `.vstemplate` file inside creates a Visual Studio project template.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of tricks to use if you want to have more than a couple of templates and also for them to appear 'nicely' in Visual Studio, i.e. divided into directories.

1. Create a directory structure that models the sections that you want to appear
2. For each template, create a directory to hold the files

Take a simple example of an Enum type that should be flags.. we have a directory FlagEnum which contains

### FlagEnum.cs

```
namespace $rootnamespace$
{
    using System;

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    [Flags]
    public enum $safeitemrootname$
    {
        // Suggest using hex rather than decimals as below to avoid overlapping/missing values
        A = 0x1,
        B = 0x2,
        C = 0x4,
        D = 0x8,
        E = 0x10,
        F = Ox20
    }
}
```

### MyTemplate.vstemplate

```
<VSTemplate Version="2.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="Item">
  <TemplateData>
    <DefaultName>Flags.cs</DefaultName>
    <Name>Flag Enum</Name>
    <Description>Enum that is meant to be a set of flags</Description>
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
    <SortOrder>10</SortOrder>
    <Icon Package="{FAE04EC1-301F-11d3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}" ID="4515" />
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
    <References />
    <ProjectItem SubType="Code" TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.cs"    ReplaceParameters="true">Enum.cs</ProjectItem>
  </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

Then we have a MSBUIlD file to produce the zip file - this uses the Community Tasks extension to get the Zip ability

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build"     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" >
    <!-- Import a bunch of external targets -->
    <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets"/>

    <!-- The templates we want to produce -->
    <ItemGroup>
               <ItemTemplate Include="FlagEnum" />
               <!--
    <ItemTemplate Include="GlobalConfigurationTask">
        <Category>Configuration\</Category>
       </ItemTemplate>
                -->
    </ItemGroup>

   <!-- Ok, standard action is to create clean zip files -->
   <Target Name="Build" DependsOnTargets="Clean;Zip;" />

    <Target Name="Clean">
    <!-- Need this for the first time through when Build doesn't exist -->
    <MakeDir Directories="Build" Condition="!Exists('Build')" />
    <!-- Can't delete it if it has contents, so delete them first -->
    <Delete Include="Build\**\*.*" Condition="!Exists('Build')" />
    <RemoveDir Directories="Build" />
    <MakeDir Directories="Build" Condition="!Exists('Build')" />
    </Target>

    <Target Name="Zip" Outputs="%(ItemTemplate.Identity)" >
        <MakeDir Directories="Build\%(ItemTemplate.Category)" Condition="%(ItemTemplate.Category) != ''" />
        <CreateItem Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\%(ItemTemplate.Category)%(ItemTemplate.Identity)\**\*.*" Exclude="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\%(ItemTemplate.Category)%(ItemTemplate.Identity)\**\_svn\**\*.*;$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\%(ItemTemplate.Category)%(ItemTemplate.Identity)\**\.svn\**\*.*">
            <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="ZipFiles" />
        </CreateItem>
        <Zip Files="@(ZipFiles)" ZipFileName="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Build\%(ItemTemplate.Category)%(ItemTemplate.Identity).zip" WorkingDirectory="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\%(ItemTemplate.Category)%(ItemTemplate.Identity)" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

This will produce a Build directory structure with all of the zipped templates in their correct locatons. You then just copy this to appropriate \Templates\ItemTemplates\Visual C# directory